# Swift & Firebase: Performing a Segue in After Searching/Finding Data in Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase

I have data in my real-time database in Firebase and I am wanting to use a search bar to search the database for a specific word, and if it matches, perform a segue to take me to another screen with information about that word. I'm having trouble getting started on this, any tips?

Comment: What have you implemented until now? Can you share some code?

Comment: ...and once you post your code, tell us where you are stuck. Describe the problem; is it with getting data from Firebase? Is it handling a segue? Something else? Please take a moment and review [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score -1):

As long as you are in a class that inherits from `UIViewContoller` then just call the function `performSegue(withIdentifier: "IDENTIFIER OF YOUR SEGUE", sender: self)`

and on your storyboard right click on the yellow dot above your view controller and drag it to the one you want to show and let go, select `Show` and then click the sue and name it and drop that name into the `IDENTIFIER OF YOUR SEGUE` string in the above function call